# Google Cloud AI Platform job is completed but its status is running

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine

I am facing a strange issue that status is not updated properly. I am using Google Cloud AI Platform to train my model. It's working as I expected, when the logs of the specific job shows that the job is completed (model file is stored in bucket), the job status is still Running. I don't know how to proceed further. Please ask me if you need more details.

Comment: I have just run a job for a built in model and I couldn't reproduce this behaviour. Could you please tell us what kind of model you are using? Is it built in or custom (from your code)? In either case, what kind of model is it? linear learner, wide and deep learner? Are you still seeing the status as "Running"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's a custom object detection model(MRCNN). Yes it's still says RUNNING, So I cancelled the job.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, I would recommend you reaching out to Google Cloud Platform support and send them a ticket with all the relevant information, because here we don't have any visibility of the issue.